# What is "UseRANU" parameter in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, build, package

I have created a package in VS2010 RC using the MPF (Managed Package Framework) and I get the following error. Can somebody help me out with this ??

***The "UseRANU" parameter is not supported by the "VsTemplatePaths" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.

The "VsTemplatePaths" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a wrong MPF. There are two, one for VS2008 and another for VS2010. I changed the MPF and the problem never occurred. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your .vstemplate contains a "UseRANU" parameter for the VsTemplatePaths task, which is obviously invalid. Open the .vstemplate and remove that parameter.

Comment: I don't find any .vstemplate file in my VSPackage project. I even searched for UseRANU using "Search content", still not able to locate the file. Can you help me out finding that file

Comment: the .vstemplate might be zipped.